# What is the most reliable way to implement push notifications for React Native on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I'm setting up push notifications in a React Native app for android and ios, I've been using react-native-push-notifications and PushNotificationsIOS from react-native (I tried the react community package first, but was having troubles with my app building). Just wondering from experience, what the best way to implement it would be?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that this is for local notifications, I have got remote notifications working with app center

Answer (score 0):

Different people have different opinions on this. I will share my opinion based on my experience.

Have a look at React Native Firebase (Please note that V6.0.0 does not support notification, do use V5.x.x)

The package is well documented and easy to integrate for both IOS and Android.

[React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/)

If you are using React Native 0.60+, then [this](https://medium.com/@katharinep/firebase-notification-integration-in-react-native-0-60-3a8d6c8d56ff) page will be helpful for you.